# prevent caching of underscore templates parsed by text plugin of requirejs

Tags: requirejs, underscore.js

I am using RequireJS text plugin to load templates and then evaluating in views.
The problem is that the templates gets cached. So until I clear the cache, the templates rendered always have the old content.

I'm guessing RequireJS text plugin caches the text templates.

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Caching of **rendered** templates has nothing to do with `test!` plugin. It caches only what's returned by the server. What is cached is **template**. Check your **rendering** code and insure **rendered** output is not cached / stuck in closure.

Comment: Also, try adding a cache busting urlArg during development if you're not already doing so: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs

Comment: Have you tried the cache-buster?

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple and documented on RequireJS page. All you need to do is add a `urlArgs` to your require.config:

```
urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()
```

Note that, as explained on the documentation, the above code is only for development environments and you need to either remove it or set a version number for your production code. This can also be easily done if you are using any kind of back end as you can always inject such value with a templating system.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs